# Error 134 in a MySql table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a file (mysql error file) full of this message

> [ERROR] Got error 134 when reading table './xxxx/wp_options'

I don't really know how to fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

```
MySQL error code 134 = Record was already deleted (or record file crashed)
```

**Solution :** *You need to run a table(s) repair on the database*

### Identifying table corruption

Checking tables

There are three ways to check tables. All of these work with MyISAM tables, the default, non-transactional table type, and one with InnoDB, the most mature of the MySQL transactional table types. Fortunately, MySQL now allows you to check tables while the server is still running, so corruption in a minor table need not affect everything on the server.

- The CHECK TABLE SQL statement (obviously the server must be running
  for this)
- Running the mysqlcheck command-line utility (the server can be
  running)
- Running the myisamchk command-line utility (the server must be down,
  or the tables inactive)

### Checking tables with CHECK TABLE

The first method for checking tables is to run the CHECK TABLE SQL statement while connected to the server. The syntax is:

```
CHECK TABLE tablename[,tablename2...] [option][,option2...]
```

**QUICK**

The quickest option, and does not scan the rows to check for incorrect links. Often used when you do not suspect an error.

**FAST**

Only checks tables if they have not been closed properly. Often used when you do not suspect an error, from a cron, or after a power failure that seems to have had no ill-effects.

**CHANGED**

Same as FAST, but also checks tables that have been changed since the last check.

**MEDIUM**

The default if no option is supplied. Scans rows to check that deleted links are correct, and verifies a calculated checksum for all keys with a calculated a key checksum for the rows.

**EXTENDED**

The slowest option, only used if the other checks report no errors but you still suspect corruption. Very slow, as it does a full key lookup for all keys for every row. Increasing the key-buffer-size variable in the MySQL config. file can help this go quicker.

*Note that CHECK TABLE only works with MyISAM and InnoDB tables. If CHECK finds corruption, it will mark the table as corrupt, and it will be unusable. See the Repairing tables section below for how to handle this*

### Checking tables with mysqlcheck

The second method is to run the mysqlcheck command-line utility. The syntax is:
`mysqlcheck [options] dbname tablename [tablename2... ]`.

The following options pertain to checking (mysqlcheck can also repair, as well as analyze and optimize.

```
--auto-repair
```

Used together with a check option, it will automatically begin repairing if corruption is found.

```
--check, -c
```

Checks tables (only needed if using mysqlcheck under another name, such as mysqlrepair. See the manual for more details)

```
--check-only-changed, -C
```

Same as the CHECK TABLE ... CHANGED option above.

```
--extended, -e
```

Same as the CHECK TABLE ... EXTENDED option above.

```
--fast, -F
```

Same as the CHECK TABLE ... FAST option above.

```
--medium-check, -m
```

Same as the CHECK TABLE ... MEDIUM option above.

```
--quick, -q
```

Same as the CHECK TABLE ... QUICK option above.

*Note that you can specify multiple tables, and that mysqlcheck only works with MyISAM tables.*

### Checking tables with myisamchk

Finally, there is the myisamchk command-line utility. The server must be down, or the tables inactive (which is ensured if the --skip-external-locking option is not in use). The syntax is: `myisamchk [options] tablename.MYI`, and you must be in, or specify, the path to the relevant .MYI files (each MyISAM database is stored in its own directory). These are the available check options:

```
--check, -c
```

The default option

```
--check-only-changed, -C
```

Same as the CHECK TABLE ... CHANGED option above.

```
--extend-check, -e
```

Same as the CHECK TABLE ... EXTENDED option above.

```
--fast, -F
```

Same as the CHECK TABLE ... FAST option above.

```
--force, -f
```

Will run the myisamchk repair option if any errors are found

```
--information, -i
```

Display statistics about the checked table

```
--medium-check, -m
```

Same as the CHECK TABLE ... MEDIUM option above.

```
--read-only, -T
```

Does not mark the table as checked

```
--update-state, -U
```

This option stores when the table was checked, and the time of crash, in .MYI file.

You can also use wildcard to check all the .MYI tables at the same time, for example:

```
% myisamchk *.MYI
```

*Note that myisamchk only works with MyISAM tables. For those of you still using the old ISAM table types, there is also isamchk, though there is really little reason not to upgrade to MyISAM.*

### Repairing tables

In most cases, only the index will be corrupted (the index is a separate, smaller, file with records that point to the main data file) - actual data corruption is extremely rare. Fixing most forms of corruption is relatively easy. As with checking, there are three ways to repair tables. These all only work with MyISAM tables - to repair corruption of the other table types, you will need to restore from backup:

- The REPAIR TABLE SQL statement (obviously the server must be running
  for this)
- The mysqlcheck command-line utility (the server can be running)
- The myisamchk command-line utility (the server must be down, or the
  tables inactive)

*Repairing a table requires twice as much disk space as the original table (a copy of the data is made), so make sure you are not going to run out of disk space before you start.*

### Repairing a table with REPAIR TABLE

The syntax is, as would be expected, `REPAIR TABLE tablename[,tablename1...] [options]`. This method only works with MyISAM tables. The following options are available.

**QUICK**

The quickest, as the data file is not modified.

**EXTENDED**

Will attempt to recover every possible data row file, which can result in garbage rows. Use as a last resort.

**USE_FRM**

To be used if the .MYI file is missing or has a corrupted header. Uses the .frm file definitions to rebuild the indexes.

### Repairing tables with mysqlcheck

The mysqlcheck command-line utility can be used while the server is running, and, like all the methods of repair, only works with MyISAM tables. The syntax is:

```
%mysqlcheck -r sports_results fixtures -uuser -ppass
```

### Repairing tables with myisamchk

The server must be down, or the tables inactive (which is ensured if the --skip-external-locking option is not in use). The syntax is myisamchk [options[ [tablenames]. Remember again that you must be in, or specify, the path to the relevant .MYI files. The following options are available:

```
--backup, -B
```

Makes a .BAK backup of the table before repairing it

```
--correct-checksum
```

Corrects the checksum

```
--data-file-length=#, -D #
```

Specifies the maximum length of the data file, when recreating

```
--extend-check, -e
```

Attempts to recover every possible row from the data file. This option should not be used except as a last resort, as it may produce garbage rows.

```
--force, -f
```

Overwrites old temporary .TMD files instead of aborting if it encounters a pre-existing one.

```
keys-used=#, -k #
```

Can make the process faster by specifying which keys to use. Each binary bit stands for one key starting at 0 for the first key.

```
--recover, -r
```

The most commonly used option, which repairs most corruption. If you have enough memory, increase the sort_buffer_size to make the recover go more quickly. Will not recover from the rare form of corruption where a unique key is not unique.

```
--safe-recover, -o
```

More thorough, yet slower repair option than -r, usually only used only if -r fails. Reads through all rows and rebuilds the indexes based on the rows. This also uses slightly less disk space than a -r repair since a sort buffer is not created. You should increase the key_buffer_size value to improve repair speed if there is available memory.

```
--sort-recover, -n
```

MySQL uses sorting to resolve the indexes, even if the resulting temporary files are very large.

```
--character-sets-dir=...
```

The directory containing the character sets

```
--set-character-set=name
```

Specifies a new character set for the index

```
--tmpdir=path, -t
```

Passes a new path for storing temporary files if you dont want to use the contents of the TMPDIR environment variable

```
--quick, -q
```

The fastest repair, since the data file is not modified. A second -q will modify the data file if there are duplicate keys. Also uses much less disk space since the data file is not modified.

```
--unpack, -u
```

Unpacks a file that has been packed with the myisampack utility.

An example of its usage:

```
% myisamchk -r fixtures
- recovering (with keycache) MyISAM-table 'fixtures.MYI'
Data records: 0
```

> All above information was taken from the following reference

1. [Repairing Data Base Corruption](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/10897_3300511_2/Repairing-Database-Corruption-in-MySQL.htm)
2. [How to Repair MyISAM Tables - MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-repair.html)

***Pls refer the articles if anything that I have mentioned above is unclear.Hope my answer helps!***